# Git clone - does it clone all branches?

Tags: git

I clone a remote repo which has a master branch, and a feature-branch

But when I do "git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all", I only see:

```
* e58e7f1 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
| * 714bebe (origin/feature-readme)
| * 7250765
|/
* 7cd4343
* 8c6c754
$ git branch
* master
```

It appears that feature-readme is not a local branch?
After I do "git checkout feature-readme", then it looks like this:

```
* e58e7f1 (master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
| * 714bebe (HEAD -> feature-readme, origin/feature-readme)
| * 7250765
|/
* 7cd4343
* 8c6c754
$ git branch
* feature-readme
  master
```

How come only after "git checkout feature-readme", only 714bebe becomes a local branch (feature-readme)?

Comment: When you clone the repo, you should get all branches, but they will remain in remotes. If you want to work on them, you need to create your local branches to track the remote branches. See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Comment: Note that the various answers on the duplicate have various errors. The *comments* on the accepted answer contain the keys to understanding what's going on.

Comment: All the branches are in remote as mentioned by fellow contributors.
The master/main Branch or whatever is the default primary branch set by the Repo owner is cloned initially.

We can check it using:
`git branch`... 
You may check out all the branches using the -a flag:
`git branch -a`